# Number of moves to bring corner cubes to its place with correct orientation?

Tags: artificial-intelligence

I am using AI to solve the 2*2 Rubix cube. **My heuristic function is the number of moves to each corner to its place with the correct orientation divided by 8, to make it admissible.**

I don't know how many moves it requires to bring a cube in the correct orientation. I need help to solve this issue.